# In Ember, why does my template want {{model.key}}, not just {{key}}?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying out Ember, and finding a discrepancy with the docs.  I used the Ember CLI to `ember generate template index` and `ember generate route index`.  Then I set up a trivial model in `index.js`:

```
model: function () {
    return {name: "Joe"};
}
```

From my reading of the docs and examples, I expected to be able to access this value simply with `{{name}}` in my index.hbs template, but instead I only get the value with `{{model.name}}`.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Ember 1.11 you could use ObjectController, that works like a proxy to corresponding route `model`, and you could write `{{name}}` for `model.name`.

ObjectController was deprecated in Ember 1.11, details here: 
http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller. So in last Ember versions you should use `Controller` class instead `ObjectController`, that doesn't work as proxy of `model`. You could think of it as of Ember Object with `model` property from corresponding route. So `{{name}}` means property of Controller, `{{model.name}}` - property of model.

For example:

```
//route
model: function () {
  return {name: "Joe"};
}

 //controller
 import Ember from 'ember';
 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   name: 'Marry'
 });

//template
{{name}} //=> Marry
{{model.name}} //=> Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a thing about explicitness but I'm not 100% sure - you can also have data sent to the template on a property other than `model` so it might be about allowing that to be more easily understood - `model` is a poor property name IMO anyway

You could use the `with` helper if the syntax is too verbose for you:

```
{{#with story}}
    <div class="intro">{{{intro}}}</div>
    <div class="body">{{{body}}}</div>
{{/with}}
```